# insert records into a table using sql script

Tags: sql

I'm trying to write a script to load records into a table based on the data in another table.
The steps are listed below.

This is in SQL and I'm new to programming. Any help with the code will be much appreciated.

```
         Table1 - Source table and has 3 columns

         Material Num Mfg Date  Sold Date

         1            1/1/2013  1/15/2013

         2            2/1/2013  null

         3            3/1/2013  null

         4            4/1/2013  4/15/2013

         5            5/1/2013  5/15/2013


         Table2 Target table

               Month/ Yr    Count

                 Jan-13   0

                 Feb-13   0

                 Mar-13   1

                 Apr-13   2

                 May-13   2
```

Comment: In your example, why is the count for Jan-13 a 0? You do have a sale for 1 1/1/2013 1/15/2013... What is the condition for counting in the second table?

Comment: Can you please give us an example of how you want your target table at least one row for the target.

Comment: Please tell us also which DBMS you are using. Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Thanks for the responses. Here are a few answers to the questions above:  a) Count repsents "how many materials were not sold at the beginning of a month. Hence it is 0 for Jan 2013. Also the date is mentioned in the mm-dd-yyyy format. Sorry if this was not clear.

Comment: Target Table will have 2 columns only. Both the columns are calculated/ derived based on the explanation.